# C# How to create a file contains 4 fields or more with records?

Tags: c#, c++, filestream, field, records

I have this code to create a file called "SomeFile.txt"

```
FileStream fsw = new FileStream("SomeFile.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
```

I want to know how to insert 4 fields and about 10 records in this file cause I'm noob at C# coding.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards.

Comment: genuinely laughed at "cause I'm noob at c# coding"

Comment: Should look into the C# StreamWriter class.

Comment: @Shane.C honesty on the internet should be rewarded. 
Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx Also Xemore can you show a bit more of what you want to write out? What structure do these fields and records live in?

Comment: Have you read anything about FileStream? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx

Comment: @TYH agreed! Also it was a good chuckle, not a downgrading one! : D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string path = @"C:\somefile.txt";
using (StreamWriter writer = (File.Exists(path) ? File.AppendText(path) : new StreamWriter(path)))
    writer.WriteLine("whatever you want to write");
```